# get next after @login_required

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am currently unable to gain access to the `next` value from the `@login_required` redirection for some untold reason. I have attached my code for the login.html page and my project settings

input `name=next` `value=''` whereas it should contain the value from `{{ next }}` which is shown in the debug dump as:

```
GET data
Variable    Value
u'next'    [u'/accounts/profile/']
```

`login.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if form.errors %}
  <p class="error"> Sorry, you have entered an incorrect username or password</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">User name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

    <input type='text' name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

`settings`:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'userprofile',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_yunite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_yunite.wsgi.application'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-ca'

TIME_ZONE = 'EST'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', '/home/user/GitHub/venv_yunite/django_yunite/static/'),
    )

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    './templates',
    '/article/templates',
)

STATIC_ROOT = "/home/user/Documents/static/"

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'userprofile.UserProfile'

from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
        "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

`views.py`:

```
def login(request):
  c={}
  c.update(csrf(request))
  return render_to_response('login.html', c)
```

Comment: Is this using your own login view here, or are you using `django.contrib.auth.views.login`? If the former, are you passing the `next` parameter into your context?

Comment: The login view is my own which I will post the code for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `next` parameter to your context.

```
def login(request):
    c = {'next' : request.GET.get('next', '/')}
    return render(request, 'login.html', c)
```

A couple of extra notes here:

1. You probably want to use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut or provide a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) as the `context_instance` argument to your `render_to_response` call.
2. Django's builtin [`login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L21) view should handle this for you unless you need special logic. There's nothing wrong with writing your own views, but Django provides a lot of functionality out of the box to reduce the amount of code you need to write yourself. The builtin views also have the benefit of being well tested and generic.

Comment: Does the builtin login include csrf?

Comment: @MattStokes Yes, CSRF protection is handled by the CsrfViewMiddleware. As long as you've got it in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings, it will be available in any template rendered with a `RequestContext` and processed by the middleware before hitting your views. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it) explain the different ways it can be used.

Comment: @MattStokes To add a bit of clarity, the `render` function I use in my answer automatically uses a `RequestContext`. This ensures that all of your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` functions are able to do their work and inject additional data into the context (such as CSRF tokens, the current logged in user, etc.) before rendering the template with it.

Answer (score 1):

What I have ended up doing is the following. To me this seems like a bit of a hack job. Is there any better way to use login with a csrf?

`views`:

```
def login(request):
  c={}
  c.update(csrf(request))
  if 'next' in request.GET:
    c['next'] = request.GET.get('next')
  return render_to_response('login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
  username = request.POST.get('username', '')
  password = request.POST.get('password', '')
  user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

  if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)

    if request.POST.get('next') != '':
      return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next'))
    else:
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
```

`login.html`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
```

Comment: I too was searching for this, and your answer was the one to help me. I think this should be the right answer.