# Return to the requested page after successfull @login_required

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Suppose this is the url after `@login_required(login_url='/account/required_login/')`:

http://ngoksy.com/accounts/login_required/?next=/article/

View for the login_require:

```
def required_login(request):
    return render(request, 'required_login.html')
```

I tried adding 'next', like it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694637/get-next-after-login-required). But it didn't help.:

```
def required_login(request):
    c = {'next' : request.GET.get('next', '/')}
    return render(request, 'login_required.html', c)
```

I have different template for login and another template for anonymous user which is redirected by `@login_required`.

required_login.html:

```
<h2>Login required! You must login to view the content.</h2>

    <form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">
        {%csrf_token%}

        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">

        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
    </form>
```

I want to pass the `next` variable after successful login of `login_required()`, and land into Articles page after that. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you trying use Django's built-in ``@login_required`` decorator? (this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required). The @ in your title led me to this thought, but then again the snippet of your view does not use the decorator and is instead a function named ``login_required``, so I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: @sthzg Yes, I am using django's `@login_required`. I have changed some of the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this.

views for `required_login`:

```
def required_login(request):
    c = {'next' : request.GET.get('next', '/')}
    return render(request, 'required_login.html', c)
```

In the template (notice the hidden input for `next`):

```
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}

    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>

    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
</form>
```

And then in the views for `auth_view`:

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)

        if request.POST.get('next') != '':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid_login')
```

I hope this will help any other noob like me! :)